# Can a lift satisfy Chen's relation, geometric condition but not be a rough path?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, stochastic-calculus, rough-paths

Let $(X,\mathbb X):[0,1]^2\to \mathbb R^d\oplus\mathbb R^{d\times d}$ satisfy the following four properties:
\begin{align}
&X_{s,t}=X_{0,t}-X_{0,s}\\
&\sup_{t\neq s}\frac{|X_{s,t}|}{|t-s|^\gamma}<\infty \text{ for some }\gamma\in (1/3,1/2]\\
&\mathbb X_{s,t}-\mathbb X_{s,u}-\mathbb X_{u,t}=X_{s,u}\otimes X_{u,t}\\
&\operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb X_{s,t})=\frac12X_{s,t}\otimes X_{s,t}
\end{align}

Is it then true that
$$\sup_{t\neq s}\frac{|\mathbb X_{s,t}|}{|t-s|^{2\gamma}}<\infty?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, this can fail. Take any geometric rough path lift $\mathbb X^{ij}$ and simply add in a *non-symmetric* way the increment of a function $F$ that fails to be $2\gamma$-Hölder. For example, take the Stratonovich lift for Brownian motion $\mathbb B^{Str}_{t}$ and define

$$\mathbb{X}_{s,t}^{ij}=\left\{\begin{matrix}(\mathbb{B}^{Str}_{s,t})^{ij}+F_{t}-F_{s} &,i< j \\
(\mathbb{B}^{Str}_{s,t})^{ij} &,i= j \\ 
 (\mathbb{B}^{Str}_{s,t})^{ij}-(F_{t}-F_{s}) &,i> j   \end{matrix}\right.$$

Comment: Great answer, thanks.